# Regular expression for a mobile number

Tags: javascript

I want to write a regular expression for a mobile number

1. The field should not be empty
2. Should be minimum of 10 - 15 char
3. The field should contain only number eg : `9042248903`

I tried using the below expression

```
^\d+([\.\,][0]{2})?$
^[0-9]+$
```

Comment: What about `^\d{10,15}$`? And if not, why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those specifications can be met with

```
^[0-9]{10,15}$
```

The start and end markers `^$` ensure there's nothing on either side.

`[0-9]` gives you a digit.

`{10,15}` meannse ten to fifteen occurrences of that digit speciffication.

Comment: `[0-9]` means match any character between 0 and 9. `{10,15}` just means at least 10 and not more than 15 occurences in a row. The ^ and $ means match the start of line and end of line respectively.

Comment: @S.Varun - there are *many* email regex examples already on the web. Try searching first.

Answer (score 2):

This will work too!

```
/^\d{10,15}$/
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
try this 

"[1-9][0-9]{9,14}"

if(!teststring.matches("[1-9][0-9]{9,14}")) {
    // blah! blah! blah!
}
```

Comment: this wouldn't match mobile numbers in my country

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
^[0-9]{10,15}$
```

[Demo with Explanation](http://regex101.com/r/yE9oR4)

[Explanation](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5E%5B0-9%5D%7B10%2C15%7D%24)